# UK Currency Regular Expression for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm after a regular expression that matches a UK Currency (ie. £13.00, £9,999.99 and £12,333,333.02), but does not allow negative (-£2.17) or zero values (£0.00 or 0).

I've tried to create one myself, but I've got in a right muddle!

Any help greatfully received.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This'll do it (well mostly...)

```
/^£?[1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$/
```

Leverages the ^ and $ to make sure no negative or other character is in the string, and assumes that commas will be used. The pound symbol, and pence are optional.

*edit: realised you said non-zero so replaced the first \d with [1-9]*

Update: it's been pointed out the above won't match £0.01. The below improvement *will* but now there's a level of complexity where it may quite possibly be better to test /[1-9]/ first and then the above - haven't benchmarked it.

```
/^£?(([1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(0\.[1-9]\d)|(0\.0[1-9]))$/
```

Brief explanation:

- Match beginning of string followed by optional "£"
- Then match *either*:

  - a >£1 amount with potential for comma separated groupings and optional pence
  - OR a <£1 >=£0.10 amount
  - OR a <=£0.09 amount
- Then match end of line

The more fractions of pence (zero in the above) you require adding to the regex the less efficient it becomes.

Comment: @Tim - Well spotted. Corrected.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks - it would have taken me ages to come up with that.

Comment: Still not matching simple numbers as £20.00 unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Under Unix/Linux, it's not always possible to type in  the '£' sign in a JavaScript file, so I tend to use its hexadecimal representation, thus:

**/^\xA3?\d{1,3}?([,]\d{3}|\d)*?([.]\d{1,2})?$/**

This seems to take care of all combinations of UK currency amounts representation that I have come across.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for that! For anyone using jquery validator btw: `jQuery.validator.addMethod('currency', function(value, element) {
   var result = value.match(/^\xA3?\d{1,3}?([,]\d{3}|\d)*?([.]\d{1,2})?$/);
   console.log("val currency"+result);
   return result;
  }, 'Please specify an amount in GBP');`

Answer (score 1):

/^\xA3?\d{1,}(?:\,?\d+)*(?:.\d{1,2})?$/; 
Explanation:

- ^ Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line.
- xA3 Matches a "£" character (char code 163)
- ? Quantifier for match between 0 and 1 of the preceding token.
- \d  Matches any digit character (0-9).
- {1,} Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
- (?: Groups multiple tokens together without creating a capture group.
- \,  Matches a "," character (char code 44).
- {1,2} Match between 1 and 2 of the preceding token.
- $  Matches the end of the string, or the end of a line if the multiline flag (

Answer (score 0):

You could just make two passes:

```
/^£\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$/
```

to validate the format, and

```
/[1-9]/
```

to ensure that at least one digit is non-zero.

This is less efficient than doing it in one pass, of course (thanks, annakata, for the benchmark information), but for a first implementation, just "saying what you want" can significantly reduce developing time.

Comment: I benchmarked it - you'd have to have 100K's of failed matches before doing a precheck becomes significantly cheaper. It's not worth the logic/readability issues.